# mremap C call does not match syscall

Tags: c, memory, system-calls

I have the following code snippet

```
    printf("mremap(%p, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, %p);\n",
                    shadow, original);
    void *result = mremap(shadow, 4096, 4096,
                    MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, original);
```

which prints

```
mremap(0x15192983b000, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0x15192983d000);
```

but `strace` shows the actual syscall is

```
mremap(0x15192983b000, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE|MREMAP_FIXED, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I have verified with the preprocessor that mremap is the glibc implementation.

What can be the cause of this? I use GLIBC 2.28, GCC 11.3.0.

It is hard to reproduce, as I only get this inside a GASNet context, but for completeness here is the program. I ran this with ibv-conduit and mpi-conduit.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gasnet.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gasnet_init(&argc, &argv);

        int *original = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        if (original == MAP_FAILED || original == NULL) {
                perror("original mmap failed");
                return -1;
        }
        original[0] = 5;
        printf("original: %p (%d)\n", original, original[0]);

        int *shadow = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        if (shadow == MAP_FAILED || shadow == NULL) {
                perror("shadow mmap failed");
                gasnet_exit(1);
        }
        shadow[0] = 13;
        printf("shadow: %p (%d)\n", shadow, shadow[0]);

        printf("mremap(%p, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, %p);\n",
                        shadow, original);
        void *result = mremap(shadow, 4096, 4096,
                        MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, original);
        if (result == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("mremap failed");
                gasnet_exit(1);
        }
        printf("original: %p (%d)\n", original, original[0]);

        gasnet_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? That the `original` is NULL while you gave it something? Also what's the point of remapping to the same size at the same location? Especially when you hardcoded the size to be 8192, then you call mremap with old_size of 4096...

Comment: @simre Yes, I pass `0x15192983d000` as fifth argument, but the syscall takes NULL. This is a minimal example reduced from a larger application where it acts as a cheap memcpy.

Comment: This is not a memcpy at all... Also as I wrote you are using mremap with a wrong "old_size". I think the compiler just see what you are doing and it is just cleverer... Also I guess it fails as the old_size is just wrong. Also MREMAP_MAYMOVE can move it to a new address so at that point requesting the resulted address as the original one just makes no sense. If it can shrink or grow, you will get the same address. If it cannot, it must move it to a new one. So I guess that's where the compiler just outsmart you

Comment: @simre It will only remap the first page, that is intended so I can easily search for mremap in the strace output. Why I use it is not important for my question, the compiler cannot do anything smart here because mremap is a library call. The assembly just says    

```405450:       ff 25 d2 8d 53 00       jmp    *0x538dd2(%rip)        # 93e22
        8 <mremap@GLIBC_2.2.5>```

Comment: That GASnet framework is probably intercepting system calls like `mmap` and `mremap`. The fifth `new_address` argument of `mremap` is optional as per the Linux man page. It could be that this framework incorrectly forwards the syscall.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Is there a good way to find out how this works? mremap is not mentioned in the code base, but it pulls a lot of external dependencies.

Comment: Can you see any `ptrace` syscalls around the `gasnet_init` function? This framework certainly does some instrumentation in one way or another.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Yes, these  

```read(16, "000 t ptrace_check_attach\n000000"..., 1024) = 1024
read(16, "T cap_ptrace_traceme\n00000000000"..., 1024) = 1024
read(16, "000 t ptrace_check_attach\n000000"..., 1024) = 1024
read(16, "T cap_ptrace_traceme\n00000000000"..., 1024) = 1024
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope", O_RDONLY) = 28
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope", O_RDONLY) = 37```

but I don't understand how that can intercept `mremap`